# Pythonic way of maintaining counter variables?

Tags: python, coding-style, pep

I have this kind of code:

```
count = 0

for line in lines:

    #do something with line
    #do something more with line
    #finish doing that thing with line

    count = count + 1
    if count % 10000 == 0:
        print count
```

Is this the right way of maintaining count-variable in python? Can I make it look better?

Comment: I would recommend that you take a look at this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go It will introduce you to more Pythonic ways of coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `enumerate()`:

```
for count, line in enumerate(lines):
    #do something here
```

`enumerate()` also accepts an optional second parameter `start`, you can use that to specify the start value of `count`. Default value of `start` is 0.

help on `enumerate`:

```
>>> help(enumerate)

 |  enumerate(iterable[, start]) -> iterator for index, value of iterable
 |  
 |  Return an enumerate object.  iterable must be another object that supports
 |  iteration.  The enumerate object yields pairs containing a count (from
 |  start, which defaults to zero) and a value yielded by the iterable argument.
 |  enumerate is useful for obtaining an indexed list:
 |      (0, seq[0]), (1, seq[1]), (2, seq[2]), ...
```

Comment: `enumerate(line, start=1)` to match the OP's post

Comment: assuming he's counting lines .... he could be counting something *in*  the lines (not likely, but possible)

Comment: Can enumerate take a generator?

Comment: will `enumerate()` affect my code performance-wise? @AshwiniChaudhary

Comment: @user yes it could be slightly slower as `enumerate` returns an iterator and to fetch an item from an iterator a call to `next()` is required each time. But the differences are negligible. And `enumerate()` is more pythonic.

Comment: On the other hand, iterators let you run your code on huge data, without worrying about the list of objects, fitting in memory. So it has its advantage too!